# Save a matrix of zero and one as a sequence of bits

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, binary, compression

I have a binary matrix 8x8 represented as an one-dimensional array

```
byte[] m = { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
             0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
             0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
             0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
             1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1 };
```

Is there a way how to save it in to binary file which would have total size of 8 bytes? Each 0 and 1 zero would be a 1 bit size.

Comment: Do the bits need to go into the bytes in a specific order? For example, should the first 0 here go into the top bit of the first byte, or in the bottom bit? Is it OK either way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following function to compress an array of 0s and 1s to an array of bytes:

```
IEnumerable<byte> Compress(byte[] a)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < a.Length / 8f; i++)
    {
        var slice = a.Skip(i * 8).Take(8);
        byte b = 0;
        foreach (var s in slice)
        {
            b <<= 1;
            if (s == 1)
                b |= 1;
        }
        yield return b;
    }
}
```

Then save to file using [`File.WriteAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8).

For example:

```
var result = Compress(m).ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes(@"d:\test.bin", result);
```